# Internet explorer margin auto doesn't work

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margin

We have a website that creates website to our customers. The website is displaying in domain and our site.

In our site we have a problem with internet explorer. There is a top navigation bar in our site and containers doesnt seem to work.

For example http://telemar.com.tr/ is working nice but the same site in  http://www.interaktifis.com/47-telemar-telekomunikasyon-elektronik-ltd-sti

doesn't display nicely.

How can i solve the problem. Thank you

Comment: Try to reduce the amount of Js because the site gets really slow.

Answer (score 1):

There's some script before the DOCTYPE on  http://www.interaktifis.com/47-telemar-telekomunikasyon-elektronik-ltd-sti that's putting the page into quirks mode. That will need to be moved to somewhere after the DOCTYPE.

Comment: Beat me to it )). The site is in the quirks mode because of it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have an error in your server side code, http://telemar.com.tr/ has no content in `#divTopNavBar` [image: No content showing]